# Internal error when sending email with Cake's email class

Tags: php, email, cakephp, gmail

I'm trying to use a Gmail account to send emails using CakePHP's [email library](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html).

In `app/Config/email.php` I have the following entry:

```
public $default = array(
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'testaccount@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'mypaswsword',
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'tls' => true
);
```

and in my controller I've put `App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');` and this in my action:

```
    $email = new CakeEmail();
    $email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'My Site'))
          ->to('you@example.com')
          ->subject('About')
          ->send('My message');
```

When I load the page I get a very undescriptive error message of `Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.`, which doesn't give me the slightest clue about what's gone wrong. I know the Gmail account settings are correct, and I'm using it just like the Cake documentation tells me to. The stack trace printed to the page tells me the error comes from this line in `CORE\Cake\Network\Email\MailTransport.php`:

```
$this->_mail($to, $email->subject(), $message, $headers, $params);
```

Does anyone know what could be going wrong here?

Edit: I've also tried using the following config:

```
public $default = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'testaccount@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);
```

but to no avail. I get exactly the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your connection and that GMAIL info is correct?